# MySQL и PHP помогите найти ошибку: error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день.

Мне необходима функция для добавления данных в БД из массива (имя ячейки => значение). То есть я готовлю массив вида

```
$data = array('title'=>'Title');
```

Таблица состоит только из id и поля тайтл. Функция готовит текст запроса и выполняет его:

```
static function insert($table,$array)
{
   $q = 'INSERT INTO `'.$table.'`';
    $rows = $values = '';
    if ($array){
        foreach($array as $key => $value)
        {
            $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
            $rows .= '`'.$key.'`,';
            if (!$value) $value = 'null';
            else $value = '\''.$value.'\'';
            $values .= $value.',';

        }
    }
    $rows[strlen($rows) - 1] = '';
        $values[strlen($values) - 1] = '';
    $q .= '('.$rows.') VALUES('.$values.')';

    return self::query($q);

}
```

В итоге получается нормальный запрос, который все же выдает ошибку :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1:
**INSERT INTO `categories`(`title`) VALUES('may')**
```

Если ввожу этот запрос напрямую в БД из phpmyadmin - он прекрасно срабатывает .
Что можно сделать? В чем суть ошибки может быть?

Answer (score 2):

Выведите переменную `$q` перед строкой. "`return self::query($q);`" Я думаю, тогда всё прояснится.

Comment: Выводил. все в порядке. Запрос нормально выполняется, если его ввести напрямую в MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Сложно что-то сказать, не зная как выглядит таблица, в которую вы пытаетесь добавить запись, но на вскидку могу предположить несколько вариантов:

1. 'categories' - возможно вы забыли название БД, а в phpmyadmin используется БД по умолчанию.
2. Кавычки то у имени таблицы и названия столбца зачем?

Остальное можно будет сказать, если увидеть структуру таблицы.

Comment: проблема решена весьма странным образом... параметры стали добавлять методом implode и все стало нормально. не знаю почему, но работает